# How to deallocate a pointer to pointer saving an address

Tags: c, malloc, valgrind

I am trying to deallocate fe. I get "invalid free()" for fe as error when using Valgrind. Is there any difference if I am trying to free a pointer to pointer saving an address instead of a double?

```
int main()
{
    double **fe = 0; int i,j;
    fe = malloc(10 * sizeof(double *));
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        fe[i] = malloc(10 * sizeof(double));
    }
    double *X; X = malloc(2 * sizeof(double));
    X[0] = 0; X[1] = 2;
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < 10; j++)
        {
            fe[i][j] = X[1];
        }
    }

    free(X);

    for (j = 0; j < 10; j++)
    {
        free(fe[j]);
    }

    free(fe);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please indent your code properly. It will help us in reading. Thank you.

Comment: Cannot reproduce. Where is your actual code? (For example, i and j are not declared anywhere in this code.)

Comment: Sorry for being sloppy. I made a few edits. (The actual code is very big so I have reproduced a simpler version of it.)

Comment: @user163917 so the `X = malloc(2 * sizeof(double *));` was a typo or that was the issue? because as per the updated code, it looks fine.

Comment: Changing your question in a way that makes already given answers un-understandable is not good idea: -1

Comment: @SouravGhosh - No it doesnt solve the problem. I still cannot free the memory for fe.

Comment: Well, in that case I will request you to post a minimal and compileable example that reproduces the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By seeing `double *X;`, I think the problem is here

```
X = malloc(2 * sizeof(double *));
```

you should be using

```
X = malloc(2 * sizeof(double));
```

or, for better,

```
X = malloc(2 * sizeof(*X));
```

However, there are other issues [missing definition of `i`, `j`] with your code presented here, as mentioned in the previous comments.

Comment: Its a minor one buddy :-)